# Properly Use TypeScript Overloads with Conditional Interface Return Types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having an issue with code that looks like this

```
interface DoThing {
  (arg: true): { hi: string };
  (arg: false): { hello: number };
}

export const doThing: DoThing = arg => {
  if (arg) {
    return {
      hi: 'hello'
    };
  }

  return {
    hello: 3
  };
};
```

The issue is with the `doThing` function which tells me

```
Types of property 'hi' are incompatible.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I'm assuming my overload is wrong, but my intent here is to pass either a `true` or `false` boolean and return different interfaces based on that.

Does anyone have any insight here?

[image: broken code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with method overloads without the `DoThing` interface.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwCYQAqAFpigOYAUAhlOQFxwxRLACUjA3nKYwM7My5OAF8A3AChQkWIlQZsuAiSE06jBNQA2fdlx7AtWiIxRIAtgCNgUUZOnR4ydFhz4ipCmoZxLECFrA1ChscJwScHCYCHDeoeGRkVDAMEhQuAmJkbxwAOTEhsa5EYniJSISJcmp6WEl2YUmcADM5ZJlEmg4fAHAAHTGVMqeVMysbH2kbJJdKD2BAxBDHqqaOuyTjdNAA):

```
export function doThing(arg: true): { hi: string }       // 1st signature
export function doThing(arg: false): { hello: number }   // 2nd signature
export function doThing(arg: boolean) {                  // actual implementation
  if (arg) {
    return {
      hi: 'hello'
    };
  }

  return {
    hello: 3
  };
}

console.log(doThing(true).hi)
console.log(doThing(false).hello)
```

---

Alternatively, you could achieve it with generics and conditional types.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwCYQAqAFpigOYA8hcoMwKeAznDFEsHAD6ICGANk2AA+ABS8o5AFxxCAShk06DZq3acA-HADecUjKZsy5OAF84M3cWD9+EGSiQBbAEbAoZgFChIsRKgxsXAISY3FJGRcICH5gXhQ5HU84OEwEOHDyRO1klLgoYBgkKFwcvLz9OABya1sIKtyU0wBuXNNPXIKikqTy2rsZAGY21paOtBwmGOAAOjtyURDSClE2DjkZ0jlWiZQp2LmIBaWwhAEhDf6Ibc8gA):

```
export function doThing<T extends true | false>(arg: T): T extends true ? { hi: string } : { hello: number }
export function doThing(arg: boolean) {
  if (arg) {
    return {
      hi: 'hello'
    };
  }

  return {
    hello: 3
  };
};

console.log(doThing(true).hi);
console.log(doThing(false).hello);
```

When `T` extends `true`, return is of type `{ hi: string }`, otherwise `{ hello: number }`.

---

I personally prefer the first example as it is easier to read (for me at least).

Comment: the first solution works thank you! Curious though why the interface method didn't work. Isn't it just two different ways of approaching the same issue?

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for you as to why. I think the interface method is good for defining types to be used throughout your API. Example, a callback argument that conforms to interface `DoThing` versus when calling `doThing`, these are the arguments you can provide and this is what they will return.

Comment: As an FYI, I was able to get the interface method to work with a tweak [see example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsAqALUBzZAbwChlkAKOKPALmTCgFcIBKOw5XOgZwf2QC+AblIUqtZPAA23Vu04QpU9HRCMAtgCNogkQOLEIADwAO6KGGQJ0IXsgAmWXCAIBeMdWSuAfEVHAYDzwWPzIyKAgwRigQULCyLmQAcmxFZSTRMmFRfVEIqJi4hLSVZABmHL0QuG40J3wRYmtbdCkIADplPHJHHHxyBmYWdtwWEWbuVo6unvqXcmlZYdSldDGgA). This casts the function assignment instead `export const doThing = (() => {}) as DoThing;`

Comment: oh nice that would do the trick. I actually ended up opening an issue about this and they pointed out it's a design limitation https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44846